# I face an error Ubuntu jammy is not supported while installing hyperledger composer prerequisite

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ubuntu-22.04

Currently I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version on Oracle virtual machine. When I try to install all the prerequisite of hyperledger composer it's showing an error Ubuntu jammy is not supported.
I am unable to run ./prereqs.sh command. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Hyperledger Composer has been unmaintained since August 2019 so I'm not surprised that you have hit problems with prereqs.

I would strongly recommend using Hyperledger Fabric directly, which is what Composer was based on. Although it is still not as straightforward as Composer, there have been quite a few improvements to Fabric over the last few years which should hopefully make getting started a bit easier. For example, have a look at the [full-stack-asset-transfer-guide](https://github.com/hyperledgendary/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide) repository, which was used in a workshop at the Hyperledger Global Forum last week.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and solved it by using Ubuntu 16.04. The hyper ledger docs actually say to use 16.04 or 14.04 in the [pre-requisite docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html)